# FFMPEG is not working with php exec() function

Tags: php, exec

i couldn't be able to execute ffmpeg command using php exec() function.
Actually all was fine and running before but by mistake we execute this command in SSH
-d safe_mode=off
after that we are facing this problem.
we have on it from the plesk pannel and also checked in php.ini it is safe_mod=on but still we couldn't be able to execute ffmpeg command through exec() function.
Can any one help me please.

Thanks,
Faraz

Comment: Your real question is how to turn safe mode off in PHP, isn't it?

Comment: You may find an answere here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+safe+mode+off

Answer (score 1):

For exec() to work, you need to have save_mode=off in your php.ini

So the fix should just be: edit the save_mode=on line inside your php.ini to save_mode=off
And restart your webserver

The ssh command should not have anything to do with your webserver.

In the php.net documentation (http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
They say:

> Note: When safe mode is enabled, you
>   can only execute files within the
>   safe_mode_exec_dir. For practical
>   reasons, it is currently not allowed
>   to have .. components in the path to
>   the executable.

Comment: It was already safe_mode=on in php.ini but still exec() is not working. please help me.

Comment: sorry, It needs to be safemode OFF (I got distracted during writint this, sorry again :/)